# How to write a for each inside template of a rendering variant

Tags: sxa, nvelocity

Inside a rendering variant I added a template. Inside that I want a for each loop. Can anyone please suggest if it's feasible.
Sitecore 9.2

Comment: if you mean for each inside a nvelocity template you can use: 
#foreach($child in $item.Children)
  $child.Name
#end

Answer (score 2):

As you mention 9.2 we can assume this is a NVelocity template. As Vlad mentioned, you can use a foreach loop there as shown here: [http://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/html/ch05s04.html](http://people.apache.org/%7Ehenning/velocity/html/ch05s04.html)

> ```
> <ul>
>   #foreach( $product in $allProducts )
>     <li>$product</li>
>   #end
> </ul>
> ```

Note however that 9.2 is the last version that support NVelocity - and it usually is not such a good idea to put too much logic inside a NVelocity template.